# Karate: Match with OR Statement

Tags: unit-testing, karate

How do I write a match statement with OR ?

```
  * def test = "ab"
  * def a = "a"
  * def b = "b"
  * match (test contains a) || (test contains b)
```

Receiving error:

> org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:5
> Expected ) but found eof (test
> ^

Comment: the main thing to note is that `match` is NOT javascript. refer to linked thread. in this simple case `* assert test.includes(a) || test.includes(b)` would work

Comment: ok you can place this in answer "* assert test.includes(a) || test.includes(b)". and I will send points thanks @PeterThomas